# Calculation of R2

Tags: python, numpy, regression, curve-fitting, scientific-computing

I try to find the coefficient of determination (R2) with thes values :
valeur_T= [45, 77, 102]

valeur_min = [55, 80, 105]

I try to calculate R2 but I always find the same result

```
        P2 = polyfit(valeur_T,valeur_min, 2)
        p= poly1d(P2)
        yhat = p(valeur_T)
        ybar = sum(valeur_min)/len(valeur_min)
        SST = sum((valeur_min - ybar)**2)
        SSreg = sum((yhat - ybar)**2)

        R2 = SSreg/SST
```

SST and SSreg always have the same values and R2=1

where is my error ?

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: Are using Python 2 or  3 (division behavior using `/` operator is not the same)?

Comment: In Python 2.7, `a/b` is an euclidian division if `a` and `b` are both `int`. You should try casting one of the values to a `float`: `ybar = float(sum(valeur_min))/len(valeur_min)` and `R2 = float(SSreg)/SST`.

Comment: with float, I have the error : unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: Look at the trackback, I can not help you much.

Comment: calculating by hand gives SST = SSreg ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fitting a second-order polynomial through 3 points, so naturally you get a perfect fit (R2=1). Your other errors seem to stem from your use of regular Python lists instead of NumPy arrays which support vectorized operations such as the one you want to carry out here:

```
SST = sum((valeur_min - ybar)**2)
```

Adding an extra data point and modifying your code to support NumPy throughout,

```
import numpy as np

valeur_T= np.array([45., 77, 102, 110])
valeur_min = np.array([55., 80, 105, 122.])

P2 = np.polyfit(valeur_T,valeur_min, 2)
p= np.poly1d(P2)
yhat = p(valeur_T)
ybar = sum(valeur_min)/len(valeur_min)
SST = sum((valeur_min - ybar)**2)
SSreg = sum((yhat - ybar)**2)

R2 = SSreg/SST
print R2
```

gives

```
0.993316215465
```

But only you can say whether this adapted code will suit your use-case, of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. I have it used to plot a graph, like this: ``plt.plot(valeur_T, valeur_min)``. But, I had to merge with another piece of code and there, there is this line ``plt.plot(valeur_T, np.polyval(P2, valeur_T))``. Do you what the last plot could mean? Thanks!